# How to organize project for white-labeling and modularization using git and maven

Tags: java, git, maven

I have a web application project which is maven-based and in git source control.
I want to find a best practice to use to organize it so that I can handle better the white-labeling and modularization issues I currently experience.

This web application is offered to clients in "modules", so only a fraction of it is included in the final war (jsp pages, classes, images, css, etc are removed). Also, each client has their own logos, branding, internationalization texts, etc (whitelabel).

Currently, I have a git branch for the full web application, multiple other git branches for each of the "modules" (and some for their combinations) and then one git branch for each of the customers.

Is there a better, more convenient way to handle this kind of project?